# Can we construct three irrational numbers $a,b,c$ such that $a+b+c \in \mathbb Q$?

Tags: irrational-numbers, rationality-testing

This is rather easily shown to be possible if no constraint is put on $a,b,c$.

However, is it also possible under the following constraint: $a, b$ and $c$ can not be rational multiples of each other.

If that constraint is too tight to allow such a construction, would it be possible if we loosen it a bit so that $a,b,c$ can be rational- but not natural multiples of each other?

Comment: What is your question, really?

Comment: $$2\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}=0$$

Comment: In fact if $a, b, c$ _are_ rational multiples of each other, then their sum will be irrational too (unless it is $0$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm, if only two of the three numbers are multiples of each other, the sum can be rational.

Comment: @matteyas: Sure.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, $-\sqrt2$ is a multiple of $-\sqrt2$ which is a multiple of $2\sqrt2$.

Comment: @GudsonChou, see my correspondence with Wojowu below to perhaps get a glimpse of my actual question (if there is one that makes sense, I'm not sure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are such triples. An example would be $\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},-\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{3}$. It's fairly easy to show that neither is a rational multiple of another.

Comment: Thank you, that is a nice constructive proof. I'll have to reconsider the proposed constraint. The real question is if there are three distinct irrationals where the only obvious correlation between them is that their sum is rational. $a = \sqrt2, b = \sqrt3, c=-\sqrt2 - \sqrt3$ are quite obviously related to each other. Do you have any suggestion on how to edit my constraint to make the distinction clear? Or perhaps you do not understand what I am looking for?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean, although specifying what you mean by "obviously related" would be (obviously) helpful. Also, note that whatever $a,b$ you take, then $c$ will have to be of the form $q-a-b$ for some rational $q$, which makes $q$ related to $a,b$.

Comment: Hmm, indeed. I don't know how to phrase the question exactly. To narrow it down a bit, I think it would suffice to answer whether there are some irrational a,b where their sum is rational. Considering my looser constraint as explained in the original question, would it be possible to e.g. find an irrational $k$ such that $k/2 + k/3$ (or some other distinct primes as divisors) is rational? Then the terms would not be natural multiples of each other.

Comment: If $k/2+k/3=k\cdot 5/6$ were rational, so would be $6/5\cdot(k\cdot 5/6)=k$. As for $a,b$ irrational with $a+b$ rational, we can take $a=\sqrt{2},b=1-\sqrt{2}$, and also $a,b$ aren't rational multiples of each other.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Regarding the second statement though, again it boils down to an obvious relation. a and b are linear combinations of 1 and √2. Anyway, thank you for your answer and comments, I think I have come to understand what bothers me and why it can't be "fixed" so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

the general solution to this is addition of any of two irrational numbers is equal to the negative of third irrational number. example as given by Wojowu so general representation of numbers  $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},-[\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}]$ so there sum is $0$ where the numbers arent rational or complex numbers  and it is all.